# Later OpenGL specs - more than shaders?

Tags: opengl, shader, specifications

I've been programming OpenGL almost entirely in the 2 specification, and don't know much about the 3 and 4 specs.
I read on some forum that the later specs of OpenGL are basically just feeding data to shaders, that do all the real work.
That would be in sharp contrast to what I understand to be OpenGL, and shaders as an auxiliary tool for things like lighting, water and other effects
I have, at best, a very basic understanding of shaders and would not be surprised to be proved wrong in any of the previously mentioned topics.  I'm just curious for a greater understanding

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. In OpenGL 3.0, nearly all of the fixed functionality is deprecated in favor of shaders. Even the built in stuff accessible from shaders is deprecated, such as modelview / projection matrices, vertex coordinates, normals, lights, etc.

The basic workflow is supposed to be as follows:

- Load geometry and per-vertex attributes through VBOs
- Load textures, shaders
- Pass stuff like matrices, lights to shaders through uniforms
- Pass per vertex values like vertex coordinates, texture coordinates, normals, through generic attribute arrays (in VBOs)
- Call `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays`

So most of the OpenGL calls you'll be making are just pushing generic data around. Instead of state functions like `glLightfv`, you'll be calling generic functions like `glUniform4f`.

Answer (score 2):

If you were already using shaders, not much changes.  You run into something that's missing, add a matrix multiply in your render code and two lines to your shader (or more likely, half a line) and life goes on.

If, like me, you were foolish enough to try to use OpenGL for something productive (i.e. rendering scientific data at high frame rates, not gaming), you're in for a little bit of hurt.  You're going to need to write (by which I mean cut+paste an example) a couple dozen lines of shader code to replace the fixed-function pipeline, and nearer a hundred lines of setup code to compile, link, and activate those shaders (along with debug output, you won't get it right on the first try).

In either case, still nothing will work.  Then you find out you need to bind a VAO.  You don't actually need to do anything with it (unless you want to use multiple VAOs for state management), you just need one because none of the other attribute/VBO stuff works without it.

When you're done, though, you can start thinking about integrating GPGPU computation using shaders or OpenCL and hand off the data for rendering, all inside the graphics memory.

Comment: I fail to see how rendering scientific data at high frame rates is any different from rendering game terrain at high frame rates.  Both benefit from removal of the fixed function pipeline.. scientific apps more so since you can likely get away with a very simple pipeline.

The downvote is for the unnecessary dig against gaming.

Comment: @Sinoth: Dig against gaming?  You mean saying it's not "productive"?  That's a fact, not a dig.  I enjoy computer games as much as the next geek.  Read a little closer, and you'll see I never said scientific data wouldn't benefit from the programmable pipeline, I said the opposite.  But before GPGPU, there wasn't much reason for scientific data to use shaders.  Particle effects, fog, etc are all very common in games, not so much in professional graphing.

Comment: @Ben: "Productive" is a charged word.. hard to claim fact or opinion over such vagueness.  Sorry if I put words in your mouth.  The negative tone of the post made me jump to that conclusion.

Comment: Upvote for the rant against VAO. And yeah, OpenGL is actually more difficult to learn than before (but easier to use once the first barrier is gone)

Comment: @Ben: Are you sure about that VAO thing? I am using VAO everywhere now anyway because at least for me (doing non-productive stuff with a considerable amount of switches), they are the best invention ever, saving me a lot of trouble. However, I'm pretty sure that not binding one (i.e. using the null VAO) used to work just fine as well once upon a time. Is that maybe dependent on whether you choose some particular profile?

Comment: @Damon: Obviously none of the answers to this question apply to the compatibility profile.  We're talking about the OpenGL 3 way of doing things, available in the core profile / forward context.

Comment: I've always used CreateContextAttribs with only MAJOR_VERSION 3 and MINOR_VERSION 3 set (or MINOR set to 1 and 2 earlier), and no other attributes. If I get that right, this is "core 3.3", albeit without "forward". Still, I don't remember any problems, ever... strange. Maybe it's the "forward" flag which does that. Oh well, let's not make a science out of it, since I'm using VAOs anyway and I love them, it doesn't really matter - was just wondering. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that geometry is easy. We have beat geometry to death. Engines exist to handle the geometry just fine.

Now, the real challenges are how do we make that geometry look more realistic? That kind of work is (best) done with shaders, so that's where the focus of the profession is headed.

Answer (score 0):

The current OpenGL specs still do most of the same geometry as ever. What they no longer do is (automatically) handle the kinds of things that are reasonably easy to do in shaders. Just for example, they no longer automatically interpolate between vertex colors to get the color for every pixel. The interpolation hardware is still there, so the shader is trivial, but still necessary.